# Magento2 currency switcher using rest API

Tags: rest, magento2

I am creating a Magento website with currency switcher, It works fine in webview. I need the same for mobile app. If the user changed the currency once, all the prices should change to selected currency.

Are we need to add any extra parameter on every API call to get chosen currency value?

Answer (score -1):

You can create multiple store views for each currency. When user change currency you can simply load that store view via API.